# AngularJS show only one ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have application with `angularjs` and error span there. I have 10 different error types, and must show 1 error `span` in one moment.

I have:

```
<div>
  <span ng-switch="{{err == 1}}" ng-model="login_error_message">Error1</span>
  <span ng-switch="{{err == 2}}" ng-model="login_error_message">Error1</span>
  <span ng-switch="{{err == 3}}" ng-model="login_error_message">Error1</span>
  ...
</div>
```

And i setup `err = 2` in my controller. But i see all spans. How can i make visible only 1 span depends on `err` value?

**Problem solved. Solution:**

```
  <span ng-show="err == 1" ng-model="login_error_message">Error1</span>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your switch is not setup correctly.

```
<div ng-switch on="err">
  <span ng-switch-when="1" ng-model="login_error_message">Error1</span>
  <span ng-switch-when="2" ng-model="login_error_message">Error1</span>
  <span ng-switch-when="3" ng-model="login_error_message">Error1</span>
</div>
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/6pJen/)**